# Why do I need to provide NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR at the component level?

Tags: angular, angular-forms

Take a look at this example:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nxjeu3

It does not work.

But if I move the `providers` from the `@NgModule` to `HelloComponent`, it does work. Why? Shouldn't providing at the `@NgModule` level or `@Component` level be the same?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Because the `NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR` is binding things to component's `:host` and linking to methods (ControlValueAccessor methods) there. Your module does not have any of those form methods (like writeValue, registerOnTouched etc). Your form element does. So providing at component level binds this for that specific element. Additionally, providing so deep down means each form control has it's own control value accessor and not a shared one.

Angular Form controls and its API is not the same as the DOM form controls. What angular does is binds to the inputs/outputs of the dom element and provides you with the results. Now, with your custom control, you must provide the same bindings there. By implementing `ControlValueAccessor` and providing `NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR`, you are telling Angular's Forms API how it can read and write values from/to your custom form control.

Take a look at the [source](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/5.2.4/packages/forms/src/directives/control_value_accessor.ts).

Comment: I notice option ```multi``` in here. So i can use multiple NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR in that element, right ?

Comment: Yes, in theory `multi` is just saying for a provider that for that specific token (`NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR`), there'll be more then one value, it'll be an array of values (or classes). Which, yes, means that your thing will be forwarded to multiple accessors.